# MS SQL Where one column is x or y and both returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as follows with **dates** in. The table has many more records but simplified for asking purposes:

```
Name     | Date       | Grade
Person 1 | 01-01-2001 | B
Person 1 | 31-01-2001 | A
Person 2 | 01-01-2001 | C
Person 3 | 31-01-2001 | A
```

I want to return both records for Person 1 but not either of the other two. AND returns nothing obviously and OR returns everything. I want to search on the **date** not the **grade** or the **person**.

So the result would be:

```
Name     | Date       | Grade
Person 1 | 01-01-2001 | B
Person 1 | 31-01-2001 | A
```

Comment: Describe why you want that result.

Comment: What is your expected output...

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE Name = 'Person 1';`

Comment: Why can't you just specify Name = 'Person 1'?

Comment: Because there are thousands of records and I want all the people who have a Grade from both of those dates. Have updated the question with more detail.

Comment: @tonyyeb You are relying on that we will guess what the requirements are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to handle this is to aggregate by person and then assert that the two dates of interest are both present:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Date IN ('2001-01-01', '2001-01-31')
    GROUP BY Name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Date) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name
```

Comment: I have updated the question. I need to search on date, not grade or person.

Comment: @tonyyeb You should have posted another question.

Comment: @tonyyeb Now I will even state that your original question was unclear.  Answer updated, hopefully what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can uses `EXISTS` to return a row if there exists another row with that name, having the other A/B grade.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where t1.Date in ('2001-01-01', '2001-01-31')
  and exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t2.Name = t1.Name
                and t2.Date in ('2001-01-01', '2001-01-31')
                and t2.Date <> t1.Date)
```

Comment: I want to search by date, not grade or person.